# Drools Vehicle routing planner but with a little difference

Tags: drools-planner

I am doing a vehicle routing that is has the following parameters:

1. Vehicle must visit the same place twice. Earlier is to setup later is to collect.
2. Both times are already per-determined in the database with lat and lng coordinates.
3. A vehicle cannot be in 2 different location at a given time

How do i go about using drools planner to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy-paste the VehicleRoutingExample
2. Rename VrpCustomer to VrpVisit
3. Add a property visitType on VrpVisit. It's a enum of SETUP and COLLECT
4. Create 2 VrpVisit visits per customer, one of each type

Maybe you 'll also need to add a constraint that the 2 visits of the same customer need to be visited by the same vehicle. Maybe even the order matters (SETUP before COLLECT)

Comment: Hi Geoffrey De Smet, thanks for the input! yes you are right, the order matters because in the database, the setup time is ALWAYS before collect, and the data is validated to be this way by server side scripting before user save in. As to regards of the 2 visits, it need not be the same vehicle, hence it is possible for one vehicle to setup then when the collect timing is near and it happens that there is another vehicle setting up for another event nearby, it can be enrouted to collect to save fuel.